# Load .jar library in runtime based on condition

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on proprietary Android embedded devices. There are currently 4 models (or HW types) in scope. For each model I have a library package from the manufacturer.

At the moment, I have solution for one of those models, which have a hardware abstraction library inside and have the .jars under `src/vendor/libs`.

```
implementation(fileTree(dir: 'src/vendor/libs', include: ['*.jar']))
```

But the resulting application is not working on the other models. I will have to use a different version of the same libraries.

My idea is to have some similar tree in app:

```
src/vendor/libs
    /model1/
    /model2/
```

Each `model#` directory would contain the different versions of libraries, and in code I would like to detect model type and use the appropriate ones.

Something similar to the following usable for native libraries:

```
System.loadLibrary("tlvtree")
```

How could I achieve it? Ideally to have one common binary APK to be used?

I know I can create a `flavor` per each model type and have different binary.